# Как переключать состояние в методе C# .NET

Tags: c#

Реализую простой фасад для сокрытия более низкоуровневых решений. 
Есть модель данных:

```
public class OutControl
{
    //---------Первая группа---------//

    public const byte Call = 0x00;
    public const byte Nop = 0x01;
    public const byte Alarm = 0x02;
    public const byte Warning = 0x03;
    public const byte Nol = 0x04;
    public const byte Action = 0x05;
    public const byte Pull = 0x06;

    //---------Вторая группа---------//

    public const byte Push = 0x00;
    public const byte Buzzer = 0x01;
    public const byte Temp = 0x02;
    public const byte Ring = 0x03;
    public const byte SwitchOff = 0x04;
    public const byte SwitchOn = 0x05;
    public const byte Reverse = 0x06;
    public const byte Reserve = 0x07;

    //-------Опкоды для записи в определенный блок------//

    public const byte FirstBlock = 0x06; 
    public const byte SecondBlock = 0x07;
}
```

Загвоздка в том, что каждая переменная относиться к определенному блоку. Первая группа (7 переменных) к FirstBlock, вторая к SecondBlock, опкоды идентичны. 
Не могу понять, как можно автоматически переключать между блоками, что бы в дальнейшем в main просто вызвать метод:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Facade facade = new Facade();

    facade.SetData(Model.OutControl.Buzzer, true);
}
```

Минуя установку блока. В метод передать только константу с опкодом, и булеву переменую для взвода флага:

```
public class Facade
{
    private Model.OutControl _outs;

    public Facade()
    {
        _outs = new Model.OutControl();
    }

    public void SetData(byte outs, bool action)
    {
        switch (как можно переключать?)
        {
            case ?:
                _outs.Set(Model.OutControl.FirstBlock, outs, action);
                break;

            case ?:
               _outs.Set(Model.OutControl.SecondBlock, outs, action);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Как решение в лоб, перебрать каждый блок в if(), но сдается мне, что можно более элегантнее сделать. Например, заменить полиморфизмом?

Comment: А внутри класса сделать группировку по классам(группам) нельзя?

Comment: Можно. Я изначально разбил на два класса, но потом для чего то снова собрал в один.

Comment: А что если иметь опкоды в разноых диапазонах? А внутри, метода делать преобразование к реальным. Ну например первая секкци 0-10, вторая 20-30. Видишь, что опкоды начинаются в диапазоне 20-30 и понимаешь, что речь о второй секции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
interface IOperation
{
    byte OpCode { get; }
    byte BlockCode { get; }
}

class Operations
{
    const byte FirstBlock = 0x06; 
    const byte SecondBlock = 0x07;

    public readonly IOperation Call = new OperationImpl(0x00, FirstBlock);
    public readonly IOperation Nop = new OperationImpl(0x01, FirstBlock);
    ...
    public readonly IOperation Push = new OperationImpl(0x00, SecondBlock);
    public readonly IOperation Buzzer = new OperationImpl(0x01, SecondBlock);
    ...

    class OperationImpl : IOperation
    {
        public byte OpCode { get; }
        public byte BlockCode { get; }
        public OperationImpl(byte opCode, byte blockCode)
            => (OpCode, BlockCode) = (opCode, blockCode);
    }
}

class Facade
{
    ...

    public void SetData(IOperation operation, bool action)
        => _outs.Set(operation.OpCode, operation.BlockCode, action);
}
```

У нас же ООП, ну чего вы в самом деле? :)

Comment: Шикарно! Спасибо!

Comment: Получается перед методом SetData(); необходимо создать объект OperationImpl и передать в конструктор Блок код и опкод?

Comment: Нет, они у вас уже все созданы в классе `Operations`, просто передайте нужный оттуда: `facade.SetData(Operations.Alarm, true);`. Это похоже на enum, только в java-style

Comment: Да, да, все разобрался! Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что тебе необходимо какое-то разделение. И самым правильным способом здесь будет замена констант на Enum'ы.

```
    //---------Первая группа---------//
enum First : byte
{
    Call = 0x00,
    Nop = 0x01,
    Alarm = 0x02,
    Warning = 0x03,
    Nol = 0x04,
    Action = 0x05,
    Pull = 0x06,
}

    //---------Вторая группа---------//
enum Second : byte
{
    Push = 0x00,
    Buzzer = 0x01,
    Temp = 0x02,
    Ring = 0x03,
    SwitchOff = 0x04,
    SwitchOn = 0x05,
    Reverse = 0x06,
    Reserve = 0x07
}

public void SetData(First outs, bool action)
{
    _outs.Set(Model.OutControl.FirstBlock, (byte)outs, action);
}

public void SetData(Second outs, bool action)
{
    _outs.Set(Model.OutControl.SecondBlock, (byte)outs, action);
}
```

Но пока непонятно - как этот инструмент используется. И если опкоды просто читаются из файла и нужно определить - к какой категории они онтосятся, а опкоды одинаковы... Ну, извините - недостаточно информации для распределения. Но ведь интерпретатор как-то их разделяет. Используй тот же признак.

Answer (score 0):

Если хочется сделать этот выбор скрыто для пользователя, то можно сделать опкоды в разных диапазонах или в разной разрядной сетке.

Например, секция один имеет опкоды в диапазоне 1-10, а вторая в 20-30.

Внутри своего метода, видишь, что опкод был передан в диапазоне 20-30 и понимаешь, что речь идет о второй секции.

Правда, в коде- это будет смотреться не интуитивно понятно...

И еще в голову пришел 1 вариант, менее "дикий":

Можно заменить числовые константы на строки, а внутри класса хранить словарик `Dictionary<string,Typle<byte,byte>`- где первый элемент кортежа- это опкод, а второй секция.

Твой метод будет принимать строку, а уже внутри ты через словарь можешь получить опкод.

Comment: Не пойдет, я не должен знать какой там у меня блок к какому относится, просто вызвал метод с двумя параметрами, а он сам должен определять, в какой блок записать.

Comment: @JDo, добавил пару вариантов.

Comment: Я тоже подумал про словарь...

Comment: @JDo, ну по моему, самое более-менее адекватное решение. В C# 8.0 появится доп. атрибут с помощью которого можно получить имя переменной, которую передали. Там чуть чище будет.